# compiz huge memory leak- ubuntu 11.04-unity

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, memory-usage

memory used by the compiz app (ID 1527) when session is started- 45-55 Mb, memory used after 2 hours, 500 MB.
i found the following bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/720446
has it been solved? is there a work around? is it related to the nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 4):

+1 for this being caused by the multiload indicator.  My system was virtually unusable due to memory (or lack thereof) while it was installed. Left running long enough, the indicator will consume massive amounts of memory.  When it was uninstalled, it was like a new computer.

Comment: It's 2014 now and there is still this issue with memory leak. I wonder if there is any alternative for indicator multiload ?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same problem and was just about to report it when I saw your message.  In my case, leaving the computer up and running overnight, the processes list in the system monitor said that Compiz was using about 2GB of memory (I have 4GB in my system).

Seeing the comment by Greg, I closed the multiload indicator and nothing has changed.  (Yet.  Perhaps it needs some time.)  Processes still shows Compiz as using 2GB of memory.  For all I know, though, it's actually now available for other processes to take as needed.  I guess I'm saying that maybe you're right, Greg, but I haven't seen anything happen yet, but I'll keep the multiload indicator closed so I can see if the memory gets released.

As for Compiz itself, it's installed but I've never changed any settings at all.

And Oleg, your English seems just fine!

Comment: Maybe it would work to run `compiz --replace&` and then `disown` in a terminal to restart compiz w/o losing your desktop session?

Answer (score 0):

The work around is to use open source driver for nvidea. If you had already installed proprietary driver, than you have to delete them first via "Additional driver" GUI. After the reboot  there will be an additional driver option .

PC sorry  for my English.

Comment: thanks for the response. i did try that and no luck.

Comment: yah... the same...  i thought the problem was gone but it take just  little longer. I Think we need to wait for update:)

Comment: following the bug report, it could be related to the multiload indicator. we will see what will happen

Comment: Although the proprietary nvidia driver is prone to causing problems, the open source driver is not really an option because the performance you get is far inferior to that of the proprietary driver.